# Passing a variable to a command - not enough arguments for format string

Tags: python, string-formatting, typeerror

hi I have the following block of test code (test lab).

```
#<snip>
client_mac = 'f8:cf:c5:a4:a2:84'
#<snip>
# issue a command1
my_command_output1 = my_wlc_session.sendcommand("grep include f8:cf:c5:a4:a2:84 \"show client summary\" \n")
# print the output
print(my_command_output1)
#
# issue a command2
my_command_output2 = my_wlc_session.sendcommand("grep include %s \"show client summary\" \n") % client_mac
# print the output
print(my_command_output2)
#<snip>
```

Command1 works as expected.

But command2 is the issue. I want some way of passing the client_mac to the command, but the code I am using results in this;

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I think this is something to do with the /n , but I need a 2nd new-line after the command for it to be executed.

Is there a better way of passing the client_mac? Or am I doing something else wrong.

Comment: Check your parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code problem is here:

```
("grep include %s \"show client summary\" \n") % client_mac
```

Your `% client_mac`  is supposed to be inside the parenthesis with the string you are formatting it into ("grep include %s \"show client summary\" \n").

The error means you specified a format string (`%s`) but did not include the variable to insert (because it was outside the parenthesis, and therefore, not part of the expression).

Re-reading your question, I believe the source of your confusion is that you thought you were passing multiple arguments to your function.  You are actually just passing a single argument, a string (which you are formatting to include the client_mac).

Answer (score 1):

Your closing parenthesis seems to be in the way. Try:

```
my_command_output2 = my_wlc_session.sendcommand("grep include %s \"show client summary\" \n" % client_mac)
```

While you're at it, the new .format() is becoming more popular, and makes bugs like this a little easier to notice. That'd look like:

```
my_command_output2 = my_wlc_session.sendcommand("grep include {} \"show client summary\" \n".format(client_mac))
```